# Get avarage value from a Table with PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have 2 tables `tache` and `tarificationtache` with `one to many` relation. On the table `tarification` I have `tache_id` , `tarif` and `technicien_id`. On table `tache` I have `id` , `libelle_tache` and `tarif`

I would like on page `show.blade.php` to shown the average of all `tarif` from `tarificationtache tarif` where the `tache_id = id` from `table tache` .

**Tachecontroller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tache;
use App\Metier;
use App\Technicien;
class TacheController extends Controller
{

protected function validator(array $data)
{
return Validator::make($data, [
    'Tarif' => 'required|floatval(6.3)',

]);
}
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function index(Request $request)
{


$tache=tache::with(['metier'])->get();

$search = $request->get('search');

$field = $request->get('field') != '' ? $request->get('field') : 
'libelle_tache';
$sort = $request->get('sort') != '' ? $request->get('sort') : 'asc';
$tache = new tache();
if ($request)

$tache = $tache->where('libelle_tache', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orderBy($field, $sort)
    ->paginate(5)
    ->withPath('?search=' . $search . '&libelle_tache=' . $tache . '&field=' 
. $field . '&sort=' . 
 $sort);
return view('tache.index',['tache'=>$tache]);

}

/**
* Show the form for creating a new resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function create()
{

//$metiers = Costcenter::lists('libelle_metier', 'id');
$metiers = Metier::orderBy('libelle_metier', 'asc')->get();
return view('tache.create')->with('metiers', $metiers);
}

/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function store(Request $request)
{
$tache = new Tache();
$tache ->libelle_tache =$request->input('libelle_tache');
$tache ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
$tache ->metier_id = $request->input('metier_id');
$tache->save();
return redirect('tache');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function show($id)
{

$tache = tache::findOrFail($id);
$metier = $tache->metier;
return view('tache.show' , compact('tache'))->with('metier',$metier);

}

/**
* Show the form for editing the specified resource.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function edit($id)
{
$tache=Tache::find($id);
$metiers = Metier::orderBy('libelle_metier', 'asc')->get();
return view('tache.edit',['libelle_tache'=>$tache],['Tarif'=>$tache], 
['metier_id'=>$tache])- 
>with('metiers', $metiers);
}

 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
 // do some request validation
 $tache=Tache::find($id);
 $tache->update($request->all());
 return redirect('tache');
 }

/**
* Remove the specified resource from storage.
*
* @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
$tache =Tache::find($id);
$tache->delete();

return redirect('tache');
}
public function getTachesByMetier($metier_id)
{
$t = Metier::find($metier_id);
return response()->json(['taches' => $t->taches]);
 }
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
<h1 align="center">Detail Tache</h1>

   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="libelle_Tache">Libelle Tache</label>
            <label id="libelle_Tache" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="tache[libelle_Tache]" >{{$tache->libelle_tache}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Tarif">Tarif moyenne </label>
            <label id="Tarif" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="tache[Tarif]" >{{$tache->Tarif}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="libelle_metier">Libelle Metier</label>
            <label id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="metier[libelle_metier]" >{{$tache->metier->libelle_metier}}</label>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group" align="right">

                        <form action="{{url ('tache/'.$tache->id)}}" 
  method="post">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}

                            <a href="{{url('/tache')}}" class="btn btn- 
  default" class="btn btn-primary">Retour</a>
                            <a href="{{url('tache/'.$tache->id.'/edit')}}" 
  class="btn btn-default">Editer</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn- 
  danger">Supprimer</button>
                        </form>
        </div
 </div>
 @endsection
```

**in the tarification tache  interface each technician to a pricing of his task**
[image: tarification tache]

**and this  is the show.blade.php i like to  display the avarage of the tarif for each task**
[image: show.blade.php]

tache.php

```
  <?php

 namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

  class tache extends Model
  {
  use SoftDeletes;
  protected $guarded = [];
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

     public function metier()
     {
    return $this->belongsTo(Metier::class);
      }

       public function tarificationtache()
      {
       return $this->hasMany(Tarificationtache::class);
       }


    }
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting, however, you might want to change the question and code to better show what you're trying to achieve. Now it is quite messy, and is hard to view what you have tried, and what fails. That way we can help you easier :)

Comment: thanks  @ThomasDarvik i am nothing try and i want who can help me affect this function as it is my first project with laravel

Comment: @ThomasDarvik and now it's clearer?

Comment: I just wanted to fix the formatting, so that others may see the question more clear. I do not know how to fix your problem. Sorry. :) Hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method on your `tache` model.
Something like

```
public function getAverage() {
    //here you would get all the relationships and return the avarage
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($this->tarificationtache as $tarification) { //if tarificationtache() is the name of your relationship to your other model...
        $total =+ $tarification->tarif;
    }
    //return average by dividing total by number of tarifications
    return ($total / (count($this->tarificationtache)));
}
```

This is kinda pseudo code because I don't know what you called the relationship on the model but you get the idea?

And then on your view you can call

```
$tache->getAverage()
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAverage() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projet\resources\views\tache\show.blade.php)"

Comment: you didn't add my function? I am editing the code to match the function for the relationship.

Comment: don't forget to change `$this->tarifications` to match the name of the relationship

Comment: i have changed the methode from cotrolelr to model i have this erreur now "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projet\resources\views\tache\show.blade.php)"

Comment: @ Ben Dubuisson please if you can explane more with code because i'm new whith laravel

Comment: @ Ben Dubuisson now its run but the value is fuls for example i have the tarif on tache 1 (25.550 ... 50.620 .... 40.000) and the result shown is (13.333333333333)

Comment: now its run but the value is fuls for example i have the tarif on tache 1 (25.550 ... 50.620 .... 40.000) and the result shown is (13.333333333333)

Comment: Just change the “getAverage” function. There are comments explaining what it does.

Comment: For each Tache, it goes and adds up the value of every tarif of every tarificationtache related to the tache and divides it by the number of tarificationtache related to the tache (average). Is that not what you want? Mean average.